# Can I start a question with a pronoun?

Tags: questions, inversion

Is there any special case where the following question would be correct?

> She is the lady of the house?

Instead of the normally accepted

> Is she the lady of the house?

Comment: Look up **declarative questions**.  (Most likely it would be contracted to *she's*, by the way.)

Answer (score 3):

**declarative question**

A yes-no question that has the form of a declarative sentence but is spoken with rising intonation at the end.

Declarative sentences are commonly used in informal speech to express surprise or ask for verification. The most likely response to a declarative question is agreement or confirmation.

source: http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/Declarative-Question-term.htm

thanks to snailplane

Answer (score 0):

The declarative question response is spot on, but in everyday usage the intonation that poster describes does not necessarily need to come at the end of the sentence (though it usually does).

One way to sound more fluent is put emphasis on the verb. So in your sentence,

> She is the lady of the house?

you could pronounce it with the stress as follows,

> SHE'S the lady of the house?

Although the more stress you put on "she's" the more incredulous you seem. So if you really don't believe that the subject is the lady of the house, then you can use more stress or even raise your voice on that syllable.